# customized css keyframes for each animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I have a linear scroll animation which allows me too loop vertically through a list of images with the css:

```
@keyframes scroll {
    0% {
      transform: translateY(0);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateY(var(100px));
    }
}
.scroll-container {
    scroll 10s linear infinite;
}
```

These containers contain images of varying heights, and thus their starting heights are determined at the start and accessed via `container.scrollHeight` in Javascript. However, the scrolling animation requires the value of `var(100px)` to be the height of the container in order for the loop to be seamless. Is there a way to set the value of `var(100px)` independently for each container using javascript?

Comment: You can use `element.style.setProperty('--height', '100px')` via javascript, and then access it in css using `var(--height)`

Comment: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-an-infinite-image-slider-using-css